# Seleccionar y desselscionar radio inputs con js

Tags: javascript, html, radiobutton

Pues colegas tengo esto, pero no me manda error a consola, aunque tampoco logro de seleccionar, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
< script >
  let ord = document.querySelector("#ord");
let comp = document.querySelector("#comp");

if (ord.checked = true) {
  comp.checked = false;
} else if (comp.checked) {
  ord.checked = false;
}

<
/script>
```

```html
<input id="ord" type="radio" name="Ordinario" value="0"> Ordinario<br>
<input id="comp" type="radio" name="Complemento" value="1"> Complemento
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo solo cambié el name de ambos por el mismo nombre

```
<input id="ord" type="radio" name="tipo" value="0"> Ordinario<br>
<input id="comp" type="radio" name="tipo" value="1"> Complementontroducir el código aquí
```